# Capture a string (from a certain point) with regex not starting with certain letters

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am in the process of writing a regex that captures everything from a certain point if the string doesn't start with certain letters.

More precisely I want to capture everything from `-` up until a comma, only IF this string doesn't start with `pt`.

en-GB should capture `-GB`

But if the word starts with `pt` I simply want to skip the capture:

`pt-BR` should capture nothing.

I created this regex:

```
-[^,]*
```

Which works nicely except that this also captures strings beginning with `pt`.

Unfortunately I can't use lookbehinds since its not supported by JS, so I tried using a negative lookahead like this:

```
^(?!pt).*
```

Problem is that this captures the entire string, and not from `-`. I tried replacing `.*` with something that starts capturing at `-`but I haven't been successful so far.

I am kinda new to regex so any guideance would be helpful.

Comment: Do you just want `s.match(/^(?!pt)[A-Za-z]{2}(-[^,]+)/)[1]`?

Comment: Problem with this is that it matches the entire string. I only want to match everything from - and onwards

Comment: But you may return only the *captured* text, it is not a problem because you have access to *code*. Or do you?

Comment: I do, but ideally I should just replace each occurance, and not do string manipulation on each of the captured texts. Do you know if there is a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a sample string and expected output. Sure, there is always a way.

Comment: no-NB should return no.
en-GB should return en.
pt-BR should return pt-BR.

Comment: `s.match(/^(?:pt-[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2})/)[0]`/? See https://regex101.com/r/i37DIE/1

Comment: Nice work. I am sure I can work with this. Ideally though, I am wondering if it is possible to only capture the - and the rest of a string. So en-GB captures -GB, no-NB captures -NB, and pt-BR doesn't get captured at all. I got it to work with negative lookbehind but not sure if its possible without it.

Comment: It is difficult to get what you want, because I still do not understand what your final result should look like. It does not matter much what you match, it is more important what you capture and what you do later in the code. Ok, so let's image you have `en-GB` string. What is the final *result* you need to get? A string `en`? And you need to do it with `.replace`? Try `text.replace(/\b(?!pt-)([A-Za-z]{2})-[a-zA-Z]{2}\b/, '$1')`

Comment: That worked perfectly! Wasn't aware that you could access the captured group like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `pt-` and any two letters at the start of the string or any two other letters, you may use

```
text.match(/^(?:pt-[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2})/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i37DIE/1). Details:

- `^` -  start of string
- `(?:pt-[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2})` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `pt-[a-zA-Z]{2}` - `pt-` and any two ASCII letters
  - `|` -  or
  - `[a-zA-Z]{2}` - any  two ASCII letters

It looks like you need to use a `.replace` method for some reason. Then,  you may use

```
text.replace(/\b(?!pt-)([A-Za-z]{2})-[a-zA-Z]{2}\b/, '$1')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i37DIE/2). Details:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!pt-)` - no `pt-` allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `([A-Za-z]{2})` - Group 1: any two ASCII letters
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[a-zA-Z]{2}` - any two ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary